# How to clear a QSharedMemory

Tags: qt, shared-memory

I have an application which continuously polls a `QSharedMemory` to check if something's been written into it.

But once something has been written and retrieved, I'd like to clear the shared memory of its content.

Is there a way to do it? I do not wish to detach and attach to it again, as I might wish vital information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
QSharedData data(...);
data.lock();
memset(data.data(), '\0', data.size());
data.unlock();
```